# Elliptical rotation matrix

Tags: matrices

We can rotate a point 'circularly' about an arbitrary axis:

[the equation is here, but this site doesn't trust me enough yet to post an image.,](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/files/2009/08/rot-arbitrary-axis.png)

But as we walk theta 0 -> 2PI this takes the point around a "unit circle" around the axis you're rotating about

How can we make it so as theta 0 -> 2PI the results are about an **ellipse** of width a, height b?

I do not want to apply transformation matrices to the points after rotating them about the axis - what I'm looking for is an "elliptical" rotation matrix, if anyone knows of such a thing!

Comment: I'm closing this as insufficiently interesting to mathematicians. Please see the FAQ, and bring any discussion over to http://tea.mathoverflow.net/

Comment: are you sure?  This isn't very friendly.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can [conjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_automorphism) the rotation matrix by a matrix which carries the unit circle to the ellipse in question, e.g., the diagonal 2x2 matrix with entries a and b.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. In 2 dimensions:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&k\sin\theta\\\\ -k^{-1}\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

The idea: Scale the $x$ axis by $k$, rotate, then scale back. Now pick $k$ appropriately (left as an exercise).

Comment: Hah! Foiled by Firefox, which crashed while I was adding this answer. So Reid got there first. Oh well. 8-)